# panning map using setInterval leads to maximum call stack error in Chrome Javascript Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, setinterval

I am working on a Javascript app with Google Maps API in which users can click on a button and the map pans while the mouse button is down.

I'm using

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, "mousedown", function(event){
    interval = setInterval(mapPanFunc, 250);//fire every 250 ms
});
```

and then

```
function mapPanFunc(){
    map.panBy(offsetX, offsetY);
}
```

aswell as

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, "mouseup", function(event){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

This works but the pan is choppy. When I change that 250 to 100 in the setInterval call, I get a maximum call stack exceeded error and the page freezes. However, using Google's built in click and drag pan is not choppy.

My idea is to preload more of the Google Map in anticipation of panning. However, I am unsure how to do this or if this is really the problem.

The problem occurs in Chrome, and not in Firefox. Solution must be cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [`panTo`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) instead to move from the initial to the final point, which would already perform a smooth animation when possible. As you can read from the docs:

> Changes the center of the map to the given `LatLng`. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

If that doesn't fit your use case, you may consider using [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to achieve a smoother animation:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(...);

let animationRequest;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, 'mousedown', () => {
    panSmoothly();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, 'mouseup', () => {
    animationRequest && window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationRequest);
});

function panSmoothly() {
    animationRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        map.panBy(offsetX, offsetY);

        panSmoothly();
    });
}
```

However, with that it is still possible that you call `panBy` too fast, before the previous panning animation finishes, and get either an undesired effect or the same `maximum call stack exceeded` error. You could listen for the [`center_changed` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) to call `panSmoothly` (and so `panBy`) sequentially. Assuming users are not able to pan manually, it will look like this:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(...);

let animationRequest;
let isPanning = false;

map.addListener('center_changed',() => {
    isPanning && panSmoothly();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, 'mousedown', () => {
    isPanning = true;

    panSmoothly();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(panControl, 'mouseup', () => {
    isPanning = false;

    animationRequest && window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationRequest);
});

function panSmoothly() {
    animationRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        map.panBy(offsetX, offsetY);
    });
}
```